# Segfault with dynamic memory allocation for boolean array via pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I defined a class and one of the private variables called "Path" points to a boolean array. Class Definition:

```
class Elevator {
    public:
        Elevator();
        int Solve();
        void PrintPath();

    private:
        int lim;
        int n;
        int* w;
        int* v; 
        int** DP;
        bool* Path;    

};
```

And the constructor:

```
Elevator::Elevator ()
{
    cout << "\n\tWeight limit: "; cin >> lim;
    cout << "\n\tNumber of people: "; cin >> n;

    w = new int [n + 1];
    v = new int [n + 1];
    cout << "did w and v.\n";

    cout << "Path.\n"; 
    Path = new bool [n + 1]; // HERE 

    cout << "Does the code get here?";
    DP = new int* [n + 1];
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {    
        DP[i] = new int [lim + 1];
        for (int j = 0; j <= lim; j++)
                DP[i][j] = 0;
    }    
}
```

According to the print statements, it works up until the line I've marked with the comment "\HERE".

```
$ ./a.out 

    Weight limit: 50

    Number of people: 3
did w and v.
Path.
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I don't know what the problem is because it works for the other pointers to integers.

Comment: Use your debugger to watch the variables.

Comment: This code looks fine.  Use some kind of memory analysis tool (`valgrind`, address sanitizer from gcc/clang, whatever windows has...).

Comment: why do you start loops at `1` ? indices range from 0 to `size-1`. And why dont you use `std::vector`?

Comment: Your print statements aren't helpful unless you do an endl at the end, they will not be flushed to the screen otherwise until a random time later. Either use endl, or use a debugger

Comment: @Ron those are not the same thing, and he isn't using them everywhere. His code is almost certainly crashing after the end of this function somewhere.

Comment: Prefer containers such as _std::vector_ and _std::array_ to raw arrays and pointers. Especially in modern C++. Double pointer is rarely ever needed.

Comment: your code works fine. I debugged in VS2019.

Comment: @Salgar Thank you so much. I did that and realized that I'm actually getting a segfault for another section.

Comment: Do you delete DP [i] and Path member in destructor ?